# I can't add the position throw google map

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I want to add a position from google map in my project using this code

```
<div class="map">
    <iframe src="https://myurl"></iframe>
</div>
```

but it didn't work. I receive the message `error msg:google n'autorise pas la connexion`

Comment: can you show the link of the map?

Comment: yes of course    '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Centre+Sectoriel+de+Formation+en+T%C3%A9l%C3%A9communications,+Cit%C3%A9+el+Khadra/@36.8343872,10.1839969,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x7a21f051df1fc31!8m2!3d36.8343866!4d10.1861849">
</iframe>'

Answer (score 0):

use **google map guide** https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map instead of using `<iframe>` and it is considered a bad practice due to [securtiy concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Other_embedding_technologies)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use an iframe, you can use the [Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start). On the link, you can put your address and it will generate an iframe snippet for your address. Please note that you need to have **[API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key)** included as the value of your key parameter.

Here is a sample snippet that you can use:

```
<div id="map">
  <iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJB6jLlpY0_RIRMfzxHQUfogc&key=PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!